# Vertical Tab Bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'am pretty new on iOS. Now i work on app for iPad that need a vertical tab bar. I already looking around and found some tutorial and [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController). But it's already deprecated and get last update around 3-4 years ago. The tab bar that i want is something that will keep in place when i push or present another `viewController`, just like `navigation controller` does. Is there any trick or ready to use library for vertical tab bar? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another library not sure if you already seen it or not. But you might wanna check out https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cksidebarcontroller

Hope it fulfill the requirement.